# How can I get a job name while the job running in Databricks. It is not notebook based job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-workflows

I'm trying to get the name of the running job. I want to get the name and to send messages. Example: I deploy my job to databricks and run it. And I want this job to send message when start in slack with job name and that's why I want to get the name of the current job.

Answer (score 5):

Databricks exposes a lot of information via `spark.conf` - the configuration properties are starting with `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.`, so you can filter all configurations and search for necessary information.

For jobs (and interactive clusters as well, but slightly different), there is a configuration property `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterAllTags` that represents a JSON string with a list of dictionaries each consisting of `key` and `value` fields. For jobs you should have the `RunName` key for job name, and `JobId` for the job ID. You can convert it with something like this:

```py
import json
all_tags = {}
for tag in json.loads(spark.conf.get(
      "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterAllTags")):
  all_tags[tag['key']] = tag['value']
job_name = all_tags.get('RunName')
```

Comment: Do you know how to get workspace name? I have different environments in Databricks and I want my job to be self aware.

Comment: it depends if it's notebook or not. For notebooks you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69187852/18627, for non-notebooks, I don't remember