# Azure Databricks python command to show current cluster config

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am currently optimizing our ETL process, and would like to be able to see the existing cluster configuration used when processing data.  This way, I can track over time which worker node sizes I should use.

Is there a command to return the cluster worker # and sizes in python so I can write as a dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this information by calling [Cluster Get REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#get) - it will return JSON including the number of workers, node types, etc.  Something like this:

```py
import requests
ctx = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()
host_name = ctx.tags().get("browserHostName").get()
host_token = "your_PAT_token"
cluster_id = ctx.tags().get("clusterId").get()

response = requests.get(
    f'https://{host_name}/api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id={cluster_id}',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'}
  ).json()
num_workers = response['num_workers']
```

P.S. if you have non-notebook job, then PAT token *may* not be available, but you can generate your token, and put it there instead

Comment: Amazing!  Not sure why this was so hard to find online

Comment: I am executing parallel notebooks via executor threads...when I do this, I lose the ability to see the current context. "dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()" results in None

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I need to look (not today) - when you're executing that in the separate thread, you may need to explicitly set context. I don't remember that out of head