# Get DataBricks Notebook Run id

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have a Databricks NoteBook task in Azure datafactory, while it executes I want to fetch its run id and save it as a new field in the destination table. Is there a way you can suggest, Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001HKHkhCAH/is-it-possible-to-get-job-run-id-of-notebook-run-by-dbutilsnotbookrun

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a job name while the job running in Databricks. It is not notebook based job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906871/how-can-i-get-a-job-name-while-the-job-running-in-databricks-it-is-not-notebook)