# Is there a way to pass default parameters in Spark Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

While configuring spark jobs, I would like to pass JobId & RunId by default whether user pass it as a parameter or not.

The reason is that, I would like to fetch JobId & RunID from my scala application and I do not want to bother job creator to pass this as a parameter.

I tried using

```
dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags("jobId")
dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags("runId")
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a job name while the job running in Databricks. It is not notebook based job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906871/how-can-i-get-a-job-name-while-the-job-running-in-databricks-it-is-not-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

You can get applicationID by:

```
sc.applicationId
res0: String = app-000000000000-00000
```

Other thing is you can get stageId and taskAttemptId using `TaskContext`

```
TaskContext.get.stageId
TaskContext.get.taskAttemptId
```

You can check more options using SparkStatus Tracker. May be that can help in your use case.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkStatusTracker.html

Comment: If I am not wrong, from application ID, I cannot retrieve task & job details.

Comment: Honestly, there is no easy way to do this. Your only option is to set up cluster log delivery, which will give you access to the cluster's event log file. This event log file is JSON and contains all of the info that the SparkUI uses (and more). It will have the information you are looking for but is not trivial to parse manually. I can't think of a better option.